# how to retrieve byte array of image from sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i am convert bitmap into byte array and try to save in sqlite database and then retrieve byte array and convert byte array in Bitmap.

The problem is that I get an exception when the program is trying to get the information of "c.getBlob(0)". It's also not working for "byte[] b = c.getBlob(0)".

Possible reasons:

The file is too large? (1.2Mb)
I have to do something else to configure the kind of BLOB that it is?
Thanks!

```
            public void saveImage(byte[] imageBitmap) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Log.d("Size of imageBitmap saveImage : ",String.valueOf(imageBitmap.length));
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, imageBitmap);
    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_IMAGE, null, values);
    db.close();

}
public byte[] getImage(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery ="SELECT * FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_IMAGE +" WHERE "+ KEY_ID + " = "+ 1;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(c!=null){
        try{
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            Log.d("Size of imageBitmap getImage :",String.valueOf(c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMAGE)).length));
            byte[] b=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMAGE));
            c.close();
            return  b;
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        }
    return null;
}


// convert from bitmap to byte array
 public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
  return stream.toByteArray();
 }
// convert from byte array to bitmap
 public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {
     ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
     Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
  return theImage;//BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
 }
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace, and indicate the line it refers to.

Comment: Storing bitmap in database is bad practice. So you should store image on sdcard and store path of image on database.